# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'acc_x'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Please help
The error is ' 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'acc_x' '
Original code:

```
        data_size = len(self._all_data.acc_x.values)
```

Comment: first of this has nothing to do with tensorflow and no answer can be inferred without looking at the code you created to load the dataframe and look at the columns it has!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks correct.
May be if you can check "_all_data" which should be a dataframe really has any column named acc_x.
If you could add more details in the question, it would certainly help.